# Python + Flask: How to replace the value of a xml tag

Tags: xml, python-3.x

I am trying to rewrite an XML file at a specific point.

I have a tag ['db']['usa']['user']['id']['number'] - for example...

I need to replace the value of the tag number.
I opened the file

```
with open('myFile.xml', 'a') as file:
    myFile = xmltodict.parse(file.read())
```

and then I just say that

```
myFile['db']['usa']['user']['id']['number'] = 1
```

But it doesn't really change the value to 1

How could I open an xml file and rewrite a specific value to a tag?

Thanks

Comment: Not necessarily a dup, but see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1912434/how-do-i-parse-xml-in-python?rq=1

Comment: I can parse the xml file, that is actually not where I got stuck. My problem is that after reading the file I can not say that the value of that tag is now 1

Comment: Why do you expect the file's content to change? you never write back to the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assigned the node to a variable:

```
node = ['db']['usa']['user']['id']['number']
```

and when returning the file I wrote the variable where it should be:

```
def returnFile(node, encoded):

     return '''<ID='''+node+'''>
     <CONTENTTYPE>image/jpeg</CONTENTTYPE>
     <CONTENTS>'''+str(encoded)+'''</CONTENTS>
     </BINARY-INFO-AZRLICHTBILD>'''
```

That solved my problem